# How to give file path from table dynamically in SSIS packages?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I want to process value "excel file location" (column) from Table and SSIS should refer column value path and load that excel data into destination table.
Purpose of this task is In future we just update the file location in the table no need to change the source details in ssis.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [Execute SQL Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) in the Control Flow to obtain the Excel file path from the database, and put it into an SSIS variable.  Then, in your Data Flow, use the variable for your data source file path.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer..Could you please elaborate the explanation?

Comment: I was trying to answer at the level of detail of your question. I didn't downvote, but I guess it was someone who thought that you didn't show enough detail of your own work. Or else you just need the concept. So my answer is that you should do this in the [Control Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137681.aspx) instead of the [Data Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141122.aspx), and that you should store the Excel file location in an [SSIS variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141085.aspx). You see where you can find the detail?